# Restricted ads serving due to rewarded ads implementation

Tags: admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

I am facing some people. I got a “Must Fix” policy issue for the rewarded ads. The problem was Rewarded Ads – Disallowed Rewarded Implementation in the last 3 months before. I have tried some different ways. But that has not been solved. So that I have changed the ad unit rewarded to interstitial ads. I gave it in review at last
26 May. It is in review till now. They are not serving any ads. In this condition what I can do now?

My app:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.orbaic.miner

[image: Problem Image of my account]